# how to fetch all the details and show in Tkinter GUI by using roll number menttion in two tables in the database?

Tags: python, tkinter, xampp

I am new to tkinter , I am searching a way so that i can easily show my two tables Student and Issue Book table in database using roll number which is common in both ( and it is a primary key ) to the tkinter GUI Student Detail window. The idea is when i enter the roll number it shows the table record in student details as i mentioned the specific frames in the Gui and So how to make a function that display my database data to tkinter Gui .I am giving my Program ,please help me to give a clarify solution.

[Students_details.py](https://gist.github.com/Manpreetgujral9/a128bb343ec09ac20967f6d869a9a097)

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Comment: Ohh , I am sorry for that .But Now I got the solution of it

Answer (score 0):

The code for fetching data from database through an id and display it into two tables in the GUI is :

I made two functions one for fetching first table data .

```
def details():
    rollnum = rnum.get()
    print(rollnum)
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='', db='data')
    a = conn.cursor()

    a.execute("select * from student where rollno='"+rollnum+"'")

    results = a.fetchall()

    count = a.rowcount

    print(results)

    print(count)

    if count > 0:
        for row in results:
            rnum1.set(row[0])
            sname.set(row[1])
            fanm.set(row[2])
            mtnm.set(row[3])
            dateob.set(row[4])
            bran.set(row[5])
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("record not found")
    conn.close()
```

and second for fetching another table from database

```
def bookdetails():
    rollnum = rnum.get()
    print(rollnum)
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='', db='data')
    b = conn.cursor()
    b.execute("select * from issuebook where rollno='" + rollnum + "'")
    resultb = b.fetchall()
    countb = b.rowcount
    print(resultb)
    print(countb)
    if countb > 0:
        for row in resultb:
            booknm.set(row[1])
            booknum.set(row[2])
            dateofiss.set(row[3])
            lstdate.set(row[4])

    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("record not found")
    conn.close()
```

I created another function for calling these two function

```
def details_and_bookdetails():
    details()
    bookdetails()
```

Then I passed the function details_and_bookdetails in the button through command.